# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Single Sign On - Azure

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, azure, azure-active-directory

We are currently attempting to carry out the set-up of the Single Sign On functionality for Salesforce Marketing Cloud, however when trying the two different ways of setting it up we are receiving the following errors:

Metadata file - We are being told that no-entity ID has been specified in the file, however this is an XML response file in the Azure AD when the SF metadata file has been authenticated.

Guided configuration - We are able to configure the certificate and receive the correct thumbprint in response on saving, however when we attempt to log-in we are receiving the following error on the AD link:

SSO Fatal Profile Error

Incoming SAML message is not properly formatted, or has elements which are missing or invalid. Unable to establish security of incoming asserton.

Comment: did you find out the solution for this? I am stuck with the same issue.